# Length of the byte array is smaller than the bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, byte

I convert bitmap to byte array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

For example, my Bitmap `213x350 = 74550` pixels, 
so length byteArray `74550*4 = 298200`.

But `byteArray.length returned 57+ thousand`.

What is wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, each pixel is coded with 8 bytes, not 4, since default bitmap format is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmap is 213x350 pixels, but your byte array contains a compressed PNG image data, which does not use 4 bytes per pixel.  As your data is compressed, the total size of the PNG file is smaller.

To see it visually, just open any graphics editor (e.g. gimp) and create a new image 213x350 pixels.  Then save this image as a PNG file and look at its size.